# ClojureScript include polyfill

Tags: google-closure-compiler, clojurescript, polyfills

I want to include a polyfill in my ClojureScript application (specifically , an [EventSource polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/)).

I would like to add it like so in my leiningen profile :

```
:foreign-libs [{:file "https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/blob/master/eventsource.min.js"
                :provides ["what.namespace.should.i.put.here"]}]
```

However this polyfill doesn't provide any namespace (it is a polyfill, not a library). Is it alright to leave the namespace empty ? Will it still include the polyfill ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the polyfill to be included in the build, the `foreign-libs` declaration should provide a namespace *and* the `ns` of at least one of your modules should `:require` the same namespace.

Under simple optimization, you may take a look at the generated :output-to js file to verify the file has been properly included, likely early in the output unless the foreign-libs declaration specify namespace dependencies.